# locking objects and thread synchronization

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm formerly a C++ developer and I read the C# docs on thread synchronization but one thing isn't clear to me.

The class creates a lock object specifically to be used for critical sections:

`private System.Object lockThis = new System.Object();`

Why can't they lock onto an existing object instead? For example, let's say that I have a class called "Players" which contains a list of players that is accessed from multiple threads via the singleton design pattern.  It has "Add" and "Remove" methods.

Can I simply just lock this object instead of creating a new object to be used specifically for locks? if I can't why not?

I haven't found anything in the docs about this, as it seems to make the code look cleaner when this is done.

I.e., some psuedocode:

```
lock (Players)
{
    Players.Add(...);
    ...
    Players.Remove(...);
}
```

EDIT: Is this bad practice, discouraged, etc? Is that why it's not mentioned anywhere?

Comment: If you lock on an object that other parts of your code can access then those other parts may take the lock and cause your code to fail. By creating a private object you prevent that kind of bug.

Comment: If I read that post correctly, it has to do with public objects.  I didn't seem to mention it in my original post, but my Players class is private to my singleton class.  Nothing else can modify the instance "Player" that is created.  @Enigmativity ah okay, so it is just a suggestion then.  A good coding practice, I guess.  Should I delete this post? I'm not sure if someone else might find it handy.

Comment: Your class is private *today*. By locking on it, you are creating a *contract* that *no one in the future will change the exposure of the instance*, but if they do, nothing tells them that it is broken except for your comments, which they won't read. That's why the best practice is to lock an object whose *sole point of existing* is to be a lock; no one is going to expose that by accident.

Comment: To be perfectly frank, the idea that *any* instance of reference type can be the target of a lock is a bit of a misfeature that started (?) with Java and was continued in the CLR. It means that *every* instance of a reference type pays the price of a synchronization block even though literally more than 99.9999% of those objects will never be the target of a lock. I would rather have a dedicated type that is the only thing that can be locked.